# Rails - Destroy action asking for 'GET'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a website that a user can signup, login, and logout. I have successfully written down the signup and login part. Actually, my 'logout' link was also working yesterday. Somehow, now I am getting this error whenever I try to logout:

`No route matches [GET] "/en/logout"`

I have my 'en' locale and it's working without a problem with other paths. It's somehow asking for a [GET] route for logout and I couldn't find where I did a mistake.

session_controller:

```
def destroy
  session.delete(:user_id) 
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

All routes that I have wrote for session controller:

```
get 'login', to:'session#new'  
post 'login', to:'session#create'
delete 'logout', to: 'session#destroy'
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
  <%= render(partial:'active_nav_item', locals:{ border: true, title: translate('profile'), uri: profile_path }) %>
  <%= link_to translate('logout'), logout_path, method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %>
</ul>
```

Routes for session controller:

```
login_path  GET     /:locale/login(.:format)    session#new
            POST    /:locale/login(.:format)    session#create
logout_path DELETE  /:locale/logout(.:format)   session#destroy
```

Comment: Check what `rails routes` says. Also consider using an existing authentication gem like [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/).

Comment: I checked `rails routes` and added all session paths from routes to the question but there is not a GET for logout_path. I will check the gem as well, thanks.